# How to implement your own error view in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, error-handling

In my ASP.NET MVC application I have an ErrorController, currently having only one action method that receives a custom class called Error and renders it to the view called Error.cshtml. For now, there're only 2 properties in the Error class:

```
public class Error{
   public string UserFriendlyMmessage{get;set;}
   public string ErrorMessage{get;set;}
}
```

The Error.cshtml view is strongly typed to the Error class. Whenever an exception is thrown inside an action method I do the following:

```
Error error = new Error { UserFriendlyText = "The friendly message", ErrorDescription = "Error to be logged" };
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(error));
```

And here's the action method of the ErrorController:

```
    public ActionResult Index(Error error)
    {
        return View(model: error, viewName:"Error");
    }
```

While this works well, this way all the model properties are shown in the url. Is there a better, more commonly used way of doing this?

Comment: When the error occurs, you could assign the `Error` to a `TempData` property, then `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error")` and in the `Index()` method get the value from `Tempdata` and render the view.

Comment: Yeah, sure I can do that? But maybe there's definitely another approach? Do people even do the way I handle errors?

Comment: I've not seen an implementation like this (and I'm not sure I like it). Personally I have a BaseController decorated with a number of `[HandleError()]` attributes that define a custom exception type and the associated view to render, Then I might say throw an `EditDeniedException("Some friendly message")` and the framework automatically displays the associated view.

Comment: Oh, @StephenMuecke, I don't like it too. Could you please post this as an answer. A little code would make what you mean more clear. I appreciate it.

Comment: Its late and I need some sleep :) I'll add an answer with some code in the morning (although its not a direct answer to yoru question so I might delete it later)

Comment: Ok, sorry, I didn't take that into account. It's 17:00 here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apart from the ugly query string, your at risk that you will exceed the query string limits, particularly if your messages are long and you add further properties to `Error`.

One option would be to persist the `Error` to a `TempData` property, then `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Error")` and in the `Index()` method get the value from `TempData` and render the view.

Another option would be to use the [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute to render views based on specific exception. For example

```
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(MyException), View = "MyError")]
[HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(AnotherException), View = "AnotherError")]
public class BaseController : Controller
{
}
```

and in the `/Views/Shared` folder, add specific error views (MyError.cshtml)

```
@model System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorInfo
....
@Model.Exception.Message // display error message
...
```

Note [HandleErrorInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorinfo%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) gives you access to the controller and action names as well as the exception details.

Then, in a specific method, if you throw an exception, the associated view will be displayed

```
public class MyController : BaseController
{
  public ActionResult SomeAction()
  {
    if(someCondition)
    {
      throw new MyException("Some friendly error message");
    }
    return View();
  }
}
```

Where `MyException` is an inbuilt exception, or you own custom exception that derives from `Exception`

Note you also need to set the following in `web.config`

```
<system.web>
  <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've noticed you're always the first one to answer my questions on MVC

Answer (score 1):

Is there any need for redirect to special error action while you are filling Error class in each action and will have the same view ? You may just do the following:

```
try{
   DoSomeStuff();
}
except (Exception e)
{
    Error error = new Error { UserFriendlyText = "The friendly message", ErrorDescription = "Error to be logged" };
    return View("Error", error);  //error view
}
return View(); //Default way
```

For ourself we have choosen another approach to show errors. There is no special view to show error. In this case user will loose context where error happened. Instead of special view we created the following structure.

1. We have BaseController with couple of useful functions:

   ```
   protected void AddErrorMessage(String errorMessage)
   {
       var errorMessages = TempData["ErrorMessages"] as List<String>;
       if (errorMessages == null)
           errorMessages = new List<String>();
       errorMessages.Add(errorMessage);
       TempData["ErrorMessages"] = errorMessages;
   }

   protected void AddSuccessMessage(String successMessage)
   {
       var successMessages = TempData["SuccessMessages"] as List<String>;
       if (successMessages == null)
           successMessages = new List<String>();
       successMessages.Add(successMessage);
       TempData["SuccessMessages"] = successMessages;
   }
   protected void AddWarningMessage(String warningMessage)
   {
       var warningMessages = TempData["WarningMessages"] as List<String>;
       if (warningMessages == null)
           warningMessages = new List<String>();
       warningMessages.Add(warningMessage);
       TempData["WarningMessages"] = warningMessages;
   }
   ```
2. We have modified _Layout to display those messages:

   ```
       @if (@TempData.ContainsKey("ErrorMessages"))
       {
           foreach (var errorMessage in TempData["ErrorMessages"] as List<String>)
           {
           <div class="alert alert-error">
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
               @(new HtmlString(errorMessage))
           </div>
           }
       }
      //The same stuff for warnings and messages
   ```
3. And in the controller we are using it as follows:

   public ActionResult CreateCustomer(Customer customer)
   {

   ```
   if (!ModelState.IsValid)
   {

       this.AddErrorMessage("Something wrong with your model");

       return View(customer);

   }
   ```

   }

We just return the same view, but with additional messages. So customer may check problem or see some warning/information message without loosing context.

Comment: Also a nice approach. I just try to avoid using Tempdata or Viewbag as much as I can

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons I don't like using `RedirectToAction` for error handling is that it changes the url of the page you're browsing, which is not the best user experience.

The simplest way would be to move your `Error.cshtml` into the `/Views/Shared` folder and make sure that file doesn't exist in the Controller throwing the error.  Then you can just do this:

```
Error error = new Error { UserFriendlyText = "The friendly message", ErrorDescription = "Error to be logged" };
return RedirectToAction("Error", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(error));
```

By default MVC convention, it will search for the `Error.cshtml` file in the "Controller" directory, and upon not finding it then search in the `Shared` directory.

If you ever need to customize the error page for that controller, you would just create a new `Error.cshtml` page inside the Controller needing the custom error.